# using <form> to call _spPageContextInfo

Tags: javascript, form, sp.js

I created an aspx page calling `_spPageContextInfo` to get information from the site.

If I include: `<form id="Main" name="Main" runat="server"></form>` on the body of the page `spPageContextInfo` brings all the information I need and runs the script just fine.

However, if I remove `<form id="Main" name="Main" runat="server"></form>` I get the following error: `'_spPageContextInfo' is undefined and Unable to get property 'results' of undefined or null reference`

I need to remove `<form id="Main" name="Main" runat="server"></form>` from the code as I want to add it the page to a webpart and webparts will not run with any reference to `<form>` in the code
Any ideas?
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused because your statement is running before _sppagecontextinfo loaded.
Can you try to get the '_spPageContextInfo" in the document ready function and see still has an issue.

Thanks,
Venkat Konjeti

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to understand how SP works. `<form></form>` is only needed when launching the page from outside SP.

I just needed to call `_spPageContextInfo` from within SP and included the script-page.aspx through the content editor's URL option.